# bluetooth disconnect D/BluetoothGatt: cancelOpen()

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, android-ble

When I call to a specific command the ble device seems to be disconnected.

I issue two commands and the device seems to be working fine.it process the request and returns a response. but when I call the third command the device automatically disconnects.

I tried adding delay to almost all the cases but still receive the error. I really don't know what to do? I actually looked at the [solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45027406/bluetooth-gatt-issue-onclientconnectionstate-status-8-clientif-29) but it is not happening the same for my connection.

```
 **D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=8 clientIf=12 
 D/BluetoothGatt: cancelOpen() - device:**
```

the above is the issue i see. does anyone know why is this happening like it should be. thanks

```
1599629181.075 ? W/bt_stack: [WARNING:bta_gattc_act.cc(1060)] bta_gattc_conn_cback: cif=3 connected=0 conn_id=0x0103 reason=0x0008
1599629181.075 ? W/bt_stack: [WARNING:bta_gattc_act.cc(1060)] bta_gattc_conn_cback: cif=4 connected=0 conn_id=0x0104 reason=0x0008
1599629181.075 ? W/bt_stack: [WARNING:bta_gattc_act.cc(1060)] bta_gattc_conn_cback: cif=6 connected=0 conn_id=0x0106 reason=0x0008
1599629181.075 ? W/bt_stack: [WARNING:bta_gattc_act.cc(1060)] bta_gattc_conn_cback: cif=7 connected=0 conn_id=0x0107 reason=0x0008
1599629181.076 ? W/bt_stack: [WARNING:bta_gattc_act.cc(1060)] bta_gattc_conn_cback: cif=8 connected=0 conn_id=0x0108 reason=0x0008
1599629181.076 ? W/bt_stack: [WARNING:bta_gattc_act.cc(1060)] bta_gattc_conn_cback: cif=9 connected=0 conn_id=0x0109 reason=0x0008
1599629181.076 ? W/bt_stack: [WARNING:bta_gattc_act.cc(1060)] bta_gattc_conn_cback: cif=10 connected=0 conn_id=0x010a reason=0x0008



    1599626204.256 ? E/BluetoothRemoteDevices: aclStateChangeCallback: device is NULL, address=FC:F5:C4:0C:99:2E, newState=1
    1599626204.257 com.buttonwillow.app.staging E/onDescriptorWrite: characteristic uuid is 923c8002-d0c5-4e1a-b9a4-a2d6befe2370 FC:F5:C4:0C:99:2E
    1599626204.257 com.buttonwillow.app.staging D/onDescriptorWrite: OnWriteCharacteristicCalled  android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt@a178ad4
    1599626204.259 ? D/BluetoothMetrics: btclass0
    1599626204.259 ? E/BtGatt.GattService: writeCharacteristic() - No connection for FC:F5:C4:0C:99:2E...
    1599626204.260 com.buttonwillow.app.staging D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=8 clientIf=12 device=FC:F5:C4:0C:99:2E
    1599626204.260 com.buttonwillow.app.staging D/BluetoothGatt: cancelOpen() - device: FC:F5:C4:0C:99:2E
    1599626204.261 ? E/BluetoothMetrics: CheckinEvent exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String java.lang.CharSequence.toString()' on a null object reference
    1599626204.262 ? E/bt_btif: No such connection need to be cancelled
    1599626204.262 ? E/bt_stack: [ERROR:bta_gattc_utils.cc(464)] bta_gattc_mark_bg_conn unable to find the bg connection mask for: fc:f5:c4:0c:99:2e
    1599626204.263 com.buttonwillow.app.staging D/BluetoothGatt: cancelOpen() - device: FC:F5:C4:0C:99:2E
    1599626204.265 ? E/bt_btif: No such connection need to be cancelled
    1599626204.265 ? E/bt_stack: [ERROR:bta_gattc_utils.cc(464)] bta_gattc_mark_bg_conn unable to find the bg connection mask for: fc:f5:c4:0c:99:2e
```

Comment: Maybe you should post your code? Do you call close() in onClientConnectionState()? Status 8 means the connection timed out unexpectedly on the link layer.

Comment: No, I'm not calling close or disconnect on anywhere in the code.